# HTML - Link to #anchor and add styling together?

Tags: html, css

I have these anchor links on top of the page, they refer to some scroll out infoboxes on the bottom. Upon clicking on one of the anchors, they link to the box below, but these boxes should also be straight up opened upon clicking.

How can I fix this?

This box is opened with these css values.

Closed state:

```
.collapsible-factuur-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

Opened state:

```
.toggle:checked+h3+.collapsible-factuur-content, .toggle:checked+h5+.collapsible-factuur-content {
    max-height: 300vh;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**So in recap,** the anchor should link to the box below #section-details-general and add the css value of the opened state above.

```css
#overlay {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: #99999945;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 100;
        transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    }

    #popup {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        background: #fff;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        z-index: 200;
        border-left: 4px solid #def2a6;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    #popupclose {
        float: right;
        padding: 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .popupcontent {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .popupcontent p {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: #586874;
    }

    #button {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .textdetails ul {
        list-style-type: disc;
    }

    .textdetails section {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }



    .textdetails label {
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .textdetails label.gp-product {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background: #def2a6 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Rubik;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #005e75;
        padding: 16px 0 16px 72px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .textdetails label.gp-product i {
        font-size: 32px;
        margin-left: -45px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        width: 30px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .textdetails label.gp-product:after {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex-grow: 1;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #005e75;
        content: "";
        font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Pro;
        font-weight: 900;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        right: 30px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .textdetails label span {
        flex: 1;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }




    .textdetails input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapsible-factuur-content {
        max-height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    }

    .toggle:checked+h3+.collapsible-factuur-content,
    .toggle:checked+h5+.collapsible-factuur-content {
        max-height: 300vh;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<p style="margin-bottom: 500px;">
    <a class="button btn--tertiary" href="#section-details-general">Link to the block</a><br>
  <mark>this is an anchor to the block below, which should also be opened up upon clicking.</mark><br><br><br>
    <mark>In the actual enviroment there is quite a big space in between these two blocks (with images, text etc)</mark>

</p>






<section class="textdetails" style="margin-bottom: 250px;">

    <!-- Details general -->
    <section id=" section-details-general"><input class="toggle" id="collapsible-details-general" type="checkbox"
            data-hj-masked="">
        <h3>
            <label class="gp-product" for="collapsible-details-general">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                <h4>Open me</h4>
            </label>
        </h3>



        <div class="collapsible-factuur-content" id="details-general">
            <p><mark>More info here</mark></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus nunc ac arcu venenatis finibus id
                consectetur odio. Nam eget mauris efficitur, laoreet augue vel, efficitur arcu. Nullam sed arcu suscipit
                massa sodales ultrices vitae sodales odio. Quisque nisi orci, rutrum sit amet porta malesuada, commodo
                at mi. Aliquam molestie purus in ullamcorper rutrum. Nullam mollis dui sed arcu bibendum lobortis vitae
                in quam. Phasellus faucibus odio tellus, a placerat nunc malesuada sit amet. Morbi ornare sagittis
                rhoncus. Proin sagittis, nunc eget porttitor placerat, ipsum tortor elementum mi, sed mollis libero
                magna efficitur velit. Donec sed ultrices enim. </p>
        </div>
    </section>


</section>
```

Comment: Are you considering using javascript to toggle ?

Comment: You can use the CSS `:target` selector or for more flexibility use JavaScript, as already mentioned by @OldPadawan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CSS-only solution, you could use the [`:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to select an element who's `id` value matches the URL fragment:

```css
#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #99999945;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}

#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-left: 4px solid #def2a6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#popupclose {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popupcontent {
  padding: 10px;
}

.popupcontent p {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #586874;
}

#button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textdetails ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.textdetails section {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.textdetails label {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #def2a6 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Rubik;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #005e75;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 72px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product i {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product:after {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #005e75;
  content: "";
  font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Pro;
  font-weight: 900;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.textdetails label span {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.textdetails input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible-factuur-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked+h3+.collapsible-factuur-content,
.toggle:checked+h5+.collapsible-factuur-content,
:target .collapsible-factuur-content {
  max-height: 300vh;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p style="margin-bottom: 500px;">
  <a class="button btn--tertiary" href="#section-details-general">Link to the block</a><br>
  <mark>this is an anchor to the block below, which should also be opened up upon clicking.</mark><br><br><br>
  <mark>In the actual enviroment there is quite a big space in between these two blocks (with images, text etc)</mark>
</p>

<section class="textdetails" style="margin-bottom: 250px;">
  <!-- Details general -->
  <section id="section-details-general">
    <input class="toggle" id="collapsible-details-general" type="checkbox" data-hj-masked="" />
    <h3>
      <label class="gp-product" for="collapsible-details-general">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        <h4>Open me</h4>
      </label>
    </h3>
    <div class="collapsible-factuur-content" id="details-general">
      <p><mark>More info here</mark></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus nunc ac arcu venenatis finibus id consectetur odio. Nam eget mauris efficitur, laoreet augue vel, efficitur arcu. Nullam sed arcu suscipit massa sodales ultrices vitae sodales
        odio. Quisque nisi orci, rutrum sit amet porta malesuada, commodo at mi. Aliquam molestie purus in ullamcorper rutrum. Nullam mollis dui sed arcu bibendum lobortis vitae in quam. Phasellus faucibus odio tellus, a placerat nunc malesuada sit amet.
        Morbi ornare sagittis rhoncus. Proin sagittis, nunc eget porttitor placerat, ipsum tortor elementum mi, sed mollis libero magna efficitur velit. Donec sed ultrices enim. </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Otherwise you could use JavaScript to programmatically check the checkbox to open the panel:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  // Attempt to get a clicked fragment link.
  const link = target.matches('a[href^="#"]') ? target : target.closest('a[href^="#"]');
  if (link) {
    debugger;
    // Attempt to get a checkbox inside the fragment.
    const toggle = document.querySelector(`${link.hash} [type=checkbox]`);
    if (toggle) {
      // Check the checkbox.
      toggle.checked = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #99999945;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
}

#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  z-index: 200;
  border-left: 4px solid #def2a6;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#popupclose {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popupcontent {
  padding: 10px;
}

.popupcontent p {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #586874;
}

#button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.textdetails ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.textdetails section {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.textdetails label {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #def2a6 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Rubik;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #005e75;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 72px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product i {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.textdetails label.gp-product:after {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #005e75;
  content: "";
  font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Pro;
  font-weight: 900;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.textdetails label span {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.textdetails input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.collapsible-factuur-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.toggle:checked+h3+.collapsible-factuur-content,
.toggle:checked+h5+.collapsible-factuur-content {
  max-height: 300vh;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p style="margin-bottom: 500px;">
  <a class="button btn--tertiary" href="#section-details-general">Link to the block</a><br>
  <mark>this is an anchor to the block below, which should also be opened up upon clicking.</mark><br><br><br>
  <mark>In the actual enviroment there is quite a big space in between these two blocks (with images, text etc)</mark>
</p>

<section class="textdetails" style="margin-bottom: 250px;">
  <!-- Details general -->
  <section id="section-details-general">
    <input class="toggle" id="collapsible-details-general" type="checkbox" data-hj-masked="" />
    <h3>
      <label class="gp-product" for="collapsible-details-general">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        <h4>Open me</h4>
      </label>
    </h3>
    <div class="collapsible-factuur-content" id="details-general">
      <p><mark>More info here</mark></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras luctus nunc ac arcu venenatis finibus id consectetur odio. Nam eget mauris efficitur, laoreet augue vel, efficitur arcu. Nullam sed arcu suscipit massa sodales ultrices vitae sodales
        odio. Quisque nisi orci, rutrum sit amet porta malesuada, commodo at mi. Aliquam molestie purus in ullamcorper rutrum. Nullam mollis dui sed arcu bibendum lobortis vitae in quam. Phasellus faucibus odio tellus, a placerat nunc malesuada sit amet.
        Morbi ornare sagittis rhoncus. Proin sagittis, nunc eget porttitor placerat, ipsum tortor elementum mi, sed mollis libero magna efficitur velit. Donec sed ultrices enim. </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Problem is: the toggle state will remain :checked and the button "open me" won't work anymore

Comment: Which solution? For the CSS-only solution, the panel will be open because of the rule with `:target`. With the JavaScript solution, the panel can be toggled.

Comment: Yes, but seemed to me that OP wants to keep both working

Comment: Yes, I would assume OP would like it to work and fortunately it does.

Comment: On CSS only, it doesn't, hence my question about using js.

Comment: Huge thank you, I will continue with the JS solution as that one also closes. cc @OldPadawan